# Convert query for count and updated date

Tags: postgresql, query, aggregate, snowflake

I currently run the below query in Snowflake for some of my reconciliations and have never worked in PostgreSQL, which we just adopted.

```
Select count(1), min (LAST_UPDATED_DATE), max(LAST_UPDATED_DATE)
from "SOURCE"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"
```

I'm looking to do the same thing in PostgreSQL. It's one that we can run against a table that will give us the last updated date and a count when checking that movements completed.

I know Postgres can be time heavy on counts and some of these tables are massive. That aside I'm not sure how to rewrite this to begin with.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Please provide your version of PostgreSQL, also your table's DDL, the actual text of your query and the result of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) <your query>...

Comment: Why do you beleive that you have to rewrite the query?

Comment: @Lennart: Well, he does. A bit, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Starting point, mostly unchanged:

```
SELECT count(*), min(last_updated_date), max(last_updated_date)
FROM   schema.table;
```

- Be aware of (not) case sensitive behavior of identifiers in Postgres. If in doubt use legal, unquoted, lower-case names exclusively. See:

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)
- A table can optionally be schema-qualified (`schema.table`), but not database-qualified. A name like from `"SOURCE"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"` would raise:

> ```
> ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "SOURCE.SCHEMA.TABLE"
> ```

- Table names without schema-qualification are resolved according to the current `search_path`. See:

  - [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)
- `count(*)` is a bit faster than `count(1)`.
- Min and max can be read from a matching index in next-to-no time. Only the count can be slow. If your count does not have to be *exact*, consider:

  - [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/939860)